# Append using sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have a txt file and I want to use the sed command in the following points:

1. For the first 5 songs in the file, change the song name to uppercase.
   My solution was:

```
cat file.txt | sed -r 's/.*/\U&/'
```

2. With lines that contain "Font1" append the line "is bold."
   My solution was:

```
cat file.txt | sed 'Font1 a\ is bold'
```

Hope you got my point, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add addresses to your commands:

```
sed -r '1,5 s/.*/\U&/; /Font1/ a\ is bold' file.txt
```

This specifies the address range line1 to 5 for the first command, and lines that match `Font1` for the second.
Be aware that `Font1` in the first five lines will be converted first and thus not be matched by the second address definition. By the way, `sed` is capable of reading files by itself, no need for the `cat`. And, as you see, all commands can go into one single `sed` script.

Comment: I think you can still search for `Font1|FONT1` or `/Font1/i` to avoid that issue.